# libuuid not linked with libuuid-devel?

Tags: linux

i am installing asterisk13.8 on my laptop with centos6.8. when i run `./configure` by going into asterisk directory it gives an error of absence of uuid development package. i manually installed `libuuid*rpm` using `rpm -Uvh libuuid*rpm` command successfully and checked by `rpm -q libuuid*rpm` but when i tried to install `libuuid-devel*rpm` it gives following error:

```
 libuuid is needed by libuuid-devel...
```

is there any linking issue or configuration issue???

Comment: `rpm -Uvh libuuid*rpm` might not have installed the intended rpm. Please double check

Comment: it gives: libuuid-2.17.2-12.28.el6.x86_64 is installed

Comment: I will try if `rpm -Uvh libuuid*rpm libuuid-devel*rpm` together if removing libuuid.